# How to disable arrow keys, home key and end key in ag-grid as navigation?

Tags: typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an ag-grid and just want to remove the navigation with the arrow keys, the home key and the end key. But I need this keys in a custom cell because I have there a text-field which should get the event. So is there maybe a property which disables the the navigation of ag-grid with these keys?

What I have already tried in the ag-grid options:

```
suppressCellSelection: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your own custom navigation:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-keyboard-navigation/#example-custom-navigation